# Using \question and \titledquestion with the exam documentclass

Tags: exam

I want to use both `\question` and `\titledquestion` of the `exam` documentclass without messing up the gradetable. From [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171991/exam-documentclass-question-title-grading-table) we know how to patch the `questions` environment in order to preserve the grade table with the numbers of the questions. But the solution to that question works for `\titledquestion` only, it breaks down if some of the questions are typeset using the `\question` command without a  title.

For example having question 2 input with the `\question` command (see the MWE below) will result in a line "Question 2: 2...". We see that `exam` treats the number of the question as its title and thus prints it twice.
In this case I want it reduced to "Question 2...", but at the same time I want to keep the behaviour for titled questions.

---

I have tried to compare the macros with an if statement:

```
\if\thequestiontitle\thequestion ...
```

but this approach seems too simple and I couldn't get it to work anyway. My MWE attached:

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\questions}
  {\def\@currentlabel{\thequestiontitle}}
  {\def\@currentlabel{\thequestion}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
\qformat{Question~\thequestion:~\thequestiontitle\dotfill (\thepoints)}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\titledquestion{Wood}[15]
How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck
wood?
\question[10] Here the problem turns up!
\end{questions}
\gradetable[v][questions]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The easy soultion is to always use `\titledquestion`, but with an empty title.  It seems to me that the only problem is that both `\question` and `\titledquestion` use the same `\qformat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your objection is to the extra "2" in the question title...

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\questions}
  {\def\@currentlabel{\thequestiontitle}}
  {\def\@currentlabel{\thequestion}}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\questions}
  {\def\question{%
    \@bonusfalse
    \def\thequestiontitle{\csname p@question\endcsname
                          \csname thequestion\endcsname}%
    \process@question
  }}%
  {\def\question{%
    \@bonusfalse
    \def\thequestiontitle{\csname p@question\endcsname}%
    \process@question
  }}%
  {}
  {FAILED}
\makeatother
\qformat{Question~\thequestion:~\thequestiontitle\dotfill (\thepoints)}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\titledquestion{Wood}[15]
How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck
wood?
\question[10] Here the problem turns up!
\end{questions}
\gradetable[v][questions]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would it be easy to remove to colon as well? The `\qformat` contains a colon that makes sense for titled questions, but not for `\question`.

Comment: You would need two separate `\qformat`s for that.  Doable, but not trivial.